# Entity view with a collection inside not working with Blaze persistance

Tags: java, blaze-persistence

I have a problem with entity views using blaze persistence library. I want to retrieve a list of Suppliers, each one with a list of Products but I'm getting an exception while creating Entity views model.

#### Setup

- Blaze persistence core 1.6.6
- Blaze persistence Entity View 1.6.6
- Spring Data JPA 2.5.6
- Hibernate 5.4.27

I'm using Blaze base configuration shown [here](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#anchor-environment-spring).

#### Model

This is my model (I have removed some fields to be more clear):

```java
@Entity(name = "suppliers")
public class Supplier extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String businessName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier")
    private List<Product> products;
}

@Entity(name = "products")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer price;

    @ManyToOne
    private Supplier supplier;
}
```

### Entity views

```java
@EntityView(Supplier.class)
public interface SupplierWithProductsView {
    Integer getId();
    String getBusinessName();

    List<ProductView> getProducts();
}

@EntityView(Product.class)
public interface ProductView {
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
    Integer getPrice();
}
```

#### Exceptions

The exception I get at startup is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal occurence of [products] in path chain resolver!
    at com.blazebit.persistence.parser.PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.invalid(PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.java:562) ~[blaze-persistence-core-parser-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.parser.PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.visit(PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.java:468) ~[blaze-persistence-core-parser-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.parser.expression.EntityLiteral.accept(EntityLiteral.java:50) ~[blaze-persistence-core-parser-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MetamodelUtils.isIndexedList(MetamodelUtils.java:125) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MetamodelUtils.isIndexedList(MetamodelUtils.java:120) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.AttributeMapping.determineIndexed(AttributeMapping.java:333) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.attribute.AbstractMethodListAttribute.<init>(AbstractMethodListAttribute.java:61) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.attribute.MappingMethodListAttribute.<init>(MappingMethodListAttribute.java:35) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MethodAttributeMapping.getMethodAttribute(MethodAttributeMapping.java:757) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.ManagedViewTypeImpl.<init>(ManagedViewTypeImpl.java:319) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.FlatViewTypeImpl.<init>(FlatViewTypeImpl.java:41) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.ViewMappingImpl.getManagedViewType(ViewMappingImpl.java:892) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MetamodelBuildingContextImpl.getManagedViewType(MetamodelBuildingContextImpl.java:234) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.ViewMetamodelImpl.<init>(ViewMetamodelImpl.java:88) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.EntityViewManagerImpl.<init>(EntityViewManagerImpl.java:271) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

I tried to take some tests by debugging and investigating in the library code and I found that if I add `@MappingIndex` to the products list in the view, the exception thrown seems more clear. I haven't fully understood how the mapping index works but maybe it is correlated. The following is the new exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are error(s) in entity views!
The resolved possible types [java.util.List] are not assignable to the given expression type 'java.util.Collection<my.package.Product>' of the mapping expression declared by the attribute products[my.package.SupplierWithProductsView.getProducts]!
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.EntityViewManagerImpl.<init>(EntityViewManagerImpl.java:285) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.EntityViewConfigurationImpl.createEntityViewManager(EntityViewConfigurationImpl.java:206) ~[blaze-persistence-entity-view-impl-1.6.6.jar:1.6.6]
    at my.package.configurations.BlazePersistenceConfig.createEntityViewManager(BlazePersistenceConfig.java:44) ~[main/:na]

... other lines omitted
```

Anyone has any idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks fine to me. Are you using Hibernate or EclipseLink? Do you think you could share a reproducer for this? We have tons of examples that do exactly this, so I assume there is something special about your app.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I'm using Hibernate. I have just edited the question and maybe you find more useful information. Meanwhile I will create a sample project to reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianBeikov [here](https://github.com/alessandrozanola/blaze-list-view-exception-sample) you can find the sample project I created to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your sample app now and I saw this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal occurence of [products] in path chain resolver!
    at com.blazebit.persistence.parser.PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.invalid(PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.java:562)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.parser.PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.visit(PathTargetResolvingExpressionVisitor.java:468)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.parser.expression.EntityLiteral.accept(EntityLiteral.java:50)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MetamodelUtils.isIndexedList(MetamodelUtils.java:125)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MetamodelUtils.isIndexedList(MetamodelUtils.java:120)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.AttributeMapping.determineIndexed(AttributeMapping.java:333)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.attribute.AbstractMethodListAttribute.<init>(AbstractMethodListAttribute.java:61)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.attribute.MappingMethodListAttribute.<init>(MappingMethodListAttribute.java:35)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MethodAttributeMapping.getMethodAttribute(MethodAttributeMapping.java:757)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.ManagedViewTypeImpl.<init>(ManagedViewTypeImpl.java:319)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.FlatViewTypeImpl.<init>(FlatViewTypeImpl.java:41)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.ViewMappingImpl.getManagedViewType(ViewMappingImpl.java:892)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.MetamodelBuildingContextImpl.getManagedViewType(MetamodelBuildingContextImpl.java:234)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.metamodel.ViewMetamodelImpl.<init>(ViewMetamodelImpl.java:88)
    at com.blazebit.persistence.view.impl.EntityViewManagerImpl.<init>(EntityViewManagerImpl.java:271)
```

The error means that the expression `products`, which is created behind the scenes for `SupplierWithProductsView#getProducts`, is illegal. This is an unfortunate side effect of the association being named the same as the entity `ProductEntity` i.e. `@Entity(name = "products")`. I created the following bug report for this and will look into this as soon as possible: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/issues/1450

In the meantime, you could rename the association to e.g. `productList`, `seelingProducts` or something like that. Alternatively, you could also rename the entity by using `@Entity(name = "product")` i.e. omitting the `s`.